# Serverless works locally but not when deployed

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, haskell, aws-lambda, servant

I have written a simple servant server and converted it into a lambda function that queries a MySQL db in amazon RDS. I can get it to work locally with `serverless offline start` however when I deploy it (`serverless deploy`) I get the following error in my dashboard when trying to access my simple test endpoint.

```
10:24:00 am
START RequestId: 9577f510-712c-4204-b9ac-05d75defcb42 Version: $LATEST
10:24:00 am
2019-10-28T14:24:00.167Z    9577f510-712c-4204-b9ac-05d75defcb42    INFO    
10:24:00 am
2019-10-28T14:24:00.169Z    9577f510-712c-4204-b9ac-05d75defcb42    ERROR   ReferenceError: exe is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/s_apigw.js:14:66)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)
    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)
10:24:00 am
2019-10-28T14:24:00.185Z    9577f510-712c-4204-b9ac-05d75defcb42    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "exe is not defined",
    "stack": [
        "ReferenceError: exe is not defined",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/s_apigw.js:14:66)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
        "    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"
    ]
}
10:24:00 am
END RequestId: 9577f510-712c-4204-b9ac-05d75defcb42
10:24:00 am
REPORT RequestId: 9577f510-712c-4204-b9ac-05d75defcb42  Duration: 30.73 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 83 MB  Init Duration: 210.80 ms
```

Comment: What does your Lambda code look like

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my resolver. I needed to use LTS 13.*.